# Apache Tomcat 8: Getting Error while creating new Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I am getting error and it is not leaving me to create a server in eclipse IDE

[image]

What mistake have I done? Can anyone let me know whether there is any specific path for adding Apache.

Comment: Exclipse expect a tomcat 8.0 not 8.5

Comment: If your directory has all the necessary files of Tomcat 8 then just change the name of the folder to `Tomcat 8.0` and give it a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Tomcat 8.5.x and TomEE 7.x with Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024876/how-to-use-tomcat-8-5-x-and-tomee-7-x-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.3. A Tomcat 8.0 installation is expected.

Eclipse built-in Tomcat server plugin basically detects the server version based on server.info property of org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties file of Tomcat's /lib/catalina.jar
Edit version in server.info property using any ZIP or JAR aware tool.
`server.info=Apache Tomcat/8.5.3 to server.info=Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.3`

 you click [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2016/07/integrating-tomcat-85x-and-tomee-7x-in.html) or [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024876/how-to-use-tomcat-8-5-x-and-tomee-7-x-with-eclipse) for more details