# unable to link tomee plus using tomcat server adapter in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am trying link TomEE server in eclipse using already existing tomcat server adaptor but I am getting

```
 The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 8.5.3.  A Tomcat 7.0 installation is expected.
```

[image]

so any idea how to change the tomee version?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug in Eclipse:https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=262418&action=edit

You can edit a file in a jar on the server to fool the server into thinking it's 8.0.

See the first answer for a workaround: [How to use Tomcat 8.5.x and TomEE 7.x with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024876/how-to-use-tomcat-8-5-x-and-tomee-7-x-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch **catalina.jar**, as this is version number the WTP adapter looks at. It's a quite useless check, and the adapter should allow you to start the server anyway, but nobody has though of that yet.

For years and with every version of Tomcat this is always a problem.

To patch you can do the following:

- cd [tomcat or tomee home]/lib
- mkdir catalina
- cd catalina/
- unzip ../catalina.jar
- vim org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties

**Make sure it looks like the following (the version numbers all need to start with 8.0):**

---

server.info=Apache Tomcat/8.0.0

server.number=8.0.0

server.built=May 11 2016 21:49:07 UTC

---

**Then:**

- jar uf ../catalina.jar org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties
- cd ..
- rm -rf catalina