# Associating an eclipse project with a tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm new to learning Java web applications and tomcat, and am having a slight problem setting up eclipse if someone doesn't mind having a brief look please. A search came up with a few [fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380125/cannot-add-a-project-to-a-tomcat-server-in-eclipse)

> You didn't create your project as "Dynamic Web Project", so Eclipse doesn't recognize it like web project. Create new "Dynamic Web Project" or go to Properties -> Projects Facets and check Dynamic Web Module

-

> 1. right click on project name in Package Explorer view.
> 2. select Properties
> 3. Select Project Facets
> 4. Click on Runtimes tab
> 5. check server
> 6. Click on OK
>
> And now :
>
> right click on server name in Servers view
>       click on Add and Remove ...
>       move resources to the right column

From my limited knowledge it looks like I've done what has been asked here. The project was also initially set up as a Dynamic Web Project:

[image]

The book I'm studying for also says that I should change the selected server in the project properties menu, as is suggested about, but I don't see the option:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious? Or did I make a mistake when applying this [patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=262418&action=edit) for tomcat 8.5? (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024876/how-to-use-tomcat-8-5-x-and-tomee-7-x-with-eclipse))

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

*edit: **RE the response asking for me to be more specific** - I'm trying to use Tomcat with a new project. I've managed it in Netbeans before, but the book I'm working from has samples using Eclipse, and I'm just trying to make things easier for myself in the future.

Here's the section from the book that I'm following. (I've already gone Windows>Preferences>Server>RuntimeEnvironment>Add  and added Tomcat v8.5 that I had to patch in). [image]

Comment: If I go to remove Tomcat from Windows > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment it then says that the 'runtime environment is being used and deleting it will cause compilation or runtime problems'. Which makes me think that everything is set up correctly.....

Comment: At this point, what are you blocked from doing?

Comment: I was trying to just run/debug a simple sample project on a local server, it wasn't working so i went back through the set up process. but I've now managed to get it working. I'm none the wiser why it wasn't, but I'm now able to work with Tomcat through eclipse. thanks for asking though