# Integrate TomEE Plus 7.1.0 with MyEclipse CI 2018

Tags: apache-tomee, myeclipse, tomee-7

I am using MyEclipse CI 2018.9.0.
I need to define a new Server Runtime Environment based on TomEE Plus v7.1.0. 
I go through the 
 
*Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environments -> Add* 
 
wizard, but the available types under TomEE are limited to v7.0.
If I choose environment type TomEE v7.0 and select my TomEE v7.1 installation directory, I get the error that installation directory is not valid.
Alternatively, if I choose Apache Tomcat v8.5 as the type of runtime environment, I am allowed to select my TomEE v7.1 installation directory, but this is not a runtime environment that I can use to deploy J2EE applications, i.e. EAR packaged applications.
Is there any hack I could use to make the integration?
I have read the [How to use Tomcat 8.5.x and TomEE 7.x with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024876/how-to-use-tomcat-8-5-x-and-tomee-7-x-with-eclipse) post but it is more about tomcat versioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TomEE 7.0 server connector is checking for a `tomee-webapp-7.0.x.jar` file in the lib folder of the TomEE runtime installation. So all you need to do (assuming there are no gotchas with running TomEE 7.1 as TomEE 7.0) is rename the `tomee-webapp-7.1.0.jar` in that folder to `tomee-webapp-7.0.jar`.

Genuitec will be looking to add that support directly in an upcoming release. Sorry about the inconvenience.